# fastboot devices fails adb devices doesn't

Tags: fastboot, fairphone-4

Devices is a Fairphone 4.

I am following [this guide](https://doc.e.foundation/devices/FP4/install). I managed to do the "OEM unlock" and then rebooted into the bootloader using `adb reboot bootloader`. At this point however, no fastboot commands work. `fastboot devices` gives no output. Other commands hang with the message `< waiting for any device >`

The android device is plugged in to a NixOS device using [these settings](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/Android).